# При подключении registration не работает проект

Tags: python, django

Здравствуйте.

Django 1.7. Когда подключаю `'registration'` в `INSTALLED_APPS`, все валится с эксепшином `jango.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Models aren't loaded yet`. Проект пустой. Ничего не менял, не добавлял, не перегружал. В чем проблема?

Answer (score 1):

Django-registration не работает на версиях django выше 1.6